# Vectorized version of matlab code produces different result to standard loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

Right, I'm really pretty new to the concept of vectorization but I'm trying to get head round it. Currently, I'm trying to adapt some of the code that I wrote to implement canny edge detection into a vectorized form and what I don't understand is why this:

```
for r=1:fsize
    for c=1:fsize
        mask(r,c) = mask(r,c)/Z;
    end
end
```

produces a different result to this:

```
mask(r:fsize,c:fsize) = mask(r:fsize,c:fsize)/Z;
```

When my understanding is that they should do the same thing?

Comment: It's a simple typo in your second case.

Comment: `c` and `r` should be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for r=1:fsize
    for c=1:fsize
        mask(r,c) = mask(r,c)/Z;
    end
end
```

Is equivalent to

```
mask(1:fsize, 1:fsize) = mask(1:fsize, 1:fsize) / Z;
```

Note - `1:fsize` not `c:fsize`.

This is assuming that `Z` is a constant.  It would be marginally faster to do `* (1 / Z)` - doing the division just once, and then multiplying...

Answer (score 3):

What is `r`, what is `c` in the second solution? Probably you need element-wise division `./`:

```
mask = mask./Z;
```

If this does not solve your problem, please provide input data to reproduce.

Comment: r and c are indexes of the matrix, which should start at 1. Apparently I forgot to define them (an I can't do it inline)....